# SSRS displays bad space in right-aligned cells when doing word wrap

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, word-wrap

I have an SSRS report in dynamics Ax 2012 where in some languages a particular header no longer fits into the column width.

No problem right? Word wrap will take care of that... But SSRS is being silly and displays the header like this:

```
|  Hello |
|   World|
```

How can I make SSRS display the cell sensibly?

```
|   Hello|
|   World|
```

keep in mind that this has to work with several texts in several languages where number of words and their order can change...

Comment: It's wrapping correctly: it's keeping the [space] character after the first word. I'm not sure you can "fix" it, though centering it might make it look better. You might also experiment with replacing the spaces with dashes or underscores to find what you think looks best.

Comment: @RussellFox No it is not wrapping correctly. The whole point of aligning text to the right or left border is that the corresponding **visible** edges of that text lines up at that border. Word doesn't do it like this. Excel doesn't. Browsers don't. No sensible person would expect it to look like this.